# Wrap box-shadow effect on pattern background

Tags: css

I'm trying to make the Warp box-shadow effect, but all the guides I've found seem to only work on one color backgrounds. My problem is that the background is a pattern and also the width is not fixed so a png images wouldn't really work.

http://jsfiddle.net/r8K8Z/

Example taken from: http://lokeshkhinchi.wordpress.com/2010/12/10/warp-shadow-using-css-3/

Comment: The method you're using *only* works on one color background because it's applying a curve to the bottom shadow to fake the warp, and that curve is a solid color.

Comment: I understand that. I'm wondering if there is some other way around my problem.

Comment: Don't use a pattern background, or use an image and a fix width box.